# why `stack build` doesn't print the warning, but `stack ghci` does?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a new project, with the following code in `Lib.hs`

```
data ABC
  = A
  | B
  | C

abc :: ABC -> Int
abc A = 1
abc B = 2
```

I want `stack build` to fail and hint me that I didn't handle `abc C`.

I have the following flags turned on in `package.yaml`:

```
library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  tt-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - tt
```

But `stack build` compiles with no warning, no error. However, `stack ghci` is able to give me the following warnings:

```
/Users/leo/zhangchiqing/te/tt/src/Lib.hs:11:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘abc’: Patterns not matched: C
   |
11 | abc A = 1
   | ^^^^^^^^^...
```

Did I miss anything, why `stack build` doesn't fail?

GHC version 8.2.2, stack resolver: lts-11.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set various GHC options for the `tt-exe` executable target, which corresponds to the `app/` directory due to the `source-dirs` setting, but your `Lib.hs` file appears to be in a `src/` directory. Presumably, this directory contains the source code for the `library` target, which has a separate set of GHC options.

You need to specify those options for the relevant target in order for `stack build` to apply them properly. However, since you are using hpack, you can also extract them into a top-level `ghc-options` section, which will be shared between all targets. Either solution should make `stack build` produce the warning you expect.

I don’t know why `stack ghci` behaves the way it does, but I think the REPL is known to have trouble with certain multi-target or multi-project configurations, so I’m not entirely surprised it does something wrong here.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I tried your suggestion, and deleted the cached cabal file, but it still doesn't work, `stack build` passes again. I've updated with my changes in the post. Did I still miss anything?

Comment: Never mind. It works now. I should add them in either top level ghc-options, or library.ghc-options. But not both! :p